# Failed audit shows me a different post

Tags: discussion, support

I just failed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/8269757) audit. It is very clear that it is low quality.

But this is not the post I was reviewing just now. I was seeing an answer, containing a link and three code lines, which even if they were pretty succinct, would pass a review.

I can't see the [original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30030125/programmatically-convert-word-documents-to-image) nor it's answers since it seems to have been deleted

I'm pretty sure I was reviewing an *answer*, why is the failed audit panel showing me a *question*??

Is it because the original question was deleted, casting all it's answers as low quality?

---

as JonasCz states, the answer I was reviewing have been deleted, as evidenced by it not appearing in the failed audit page.

---

[image: Failed Audit Answer]

Comment: Yes, It seems (to me) you were reviewing an answer, as the top panel of the failed audit screen you link is showing "Answer: Answer not found". Below it, the question was shown for reference, but this has been deleted too. You would not have a screenshot to clarify ?

Comment: I sadly did not take a screenshot before failing the audit..

Comment: That's what I see - is that what you reviewed?

Comment: As there are no questions in Low Quality posts, It must have been answer though.

Comment: Yes @Joe, that's the answer I was seeing while reviewing

Comment: That's an answer, yes.  (The asker asks very simply "How do I convert a word doc to an image".)

Comment: @JonasCz There are no questions in LQ queue...except sometimes you do receive questions in LQ but they are always audits.. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/289627/3041194 Team is aware of this but hasn't fixed yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That answer looks sort of like spam to me, and is probably how it was flagged.  It's also probably why Martin deleted that entire question - because the question was bad, yes, but that's probably how he stumbled onto it.

It's not necessarily a bad answer, and probably doesn't deserve a spam flag, but that's probably what happened in this case.  Audits are automated, occasionally something like this happens.

As to why it showed you the question - don't know, that sounds like a mistake.  The issue is common, though, lots of other meta questions like [this one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268969/review-audit-on-answer-that-had-its-question-deleted-out-from-under-it).

Comment: Thanks Joe, this covers and clarifies all my doubts and questioning. I'll continue reviewing in peace now